# We have been quiet, but we are/were listening?

Tags: present-perfect

If "are" is used, shouldn't it mean they are listening now, but it's uncertain they were listening or not ?
Present perfect continuous covers past and present, which one then should be used ?

Comment: "Were" has the problem that it can be interpreted as past tense only. "*We were listening [but we aren't any more].*"

Comment: @Catija I don't believe there is an implication that the speaker is no longer listening with "were" in that context.

Regarding the question, I'm leaning towards it depending on what one feels the need to stress. Is the intention to respond to an accusation of having potentially not listened, or is the intention to stress that they are continuing to listen?